# How to display acute accent characters in Dropdown created in Template Tool kit

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

I am confused on why acute accents are not getting displayed correctly under a dropdown options in template tool kit.

```
[% glossary.$language.all_terms %]
```

is displayed as "Todos los Términos" in the UI. But when I use the same in the Dropdown menu, it is displayed with incorrect characters. I have attached the screenshot.

[image: The Dropdown showing the wrong data, where as same variable printed is correct]

To achieve this, I have written the template like this.

```
[% IF terms.size > 1 %]
  <select onchange="this.form.submit();">
  [%-
     IF terms.size > 1;
        terms.unshift( { name => glossary.$language.all_terms, term_id => '0' } );
        terms.unshift( { name => glossary.$language.all_current_terms, term_id => '' } );
     END;

 INCLUDE html/options.tmpl
 options   = terms,
 valuekey  = 'term_id',
 choicekey = 'name',
 selected  = form.term_id
  -%]
</select>
```

html/options.tmpl is a template which will add additional dynamic options to the same dropdown. The terms data structure is sent from the PERL module.
What is that I am doing wrong.?

Comment: What is actually being output in the HTML? My guess is that something is auto-encoding the HTML so that `&#233;` is being converted to `&amp;233;`.

Comment: @DaveCross I have added the new screenshot. when I am printing       [% glossary.$language.all_terms %] it is working fine. But when i put the same in the dropdown code section as shown above, the &eacute is not displayed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Dave, the prevailing syntax in Template Toolkit site is to use the word form of the html entity. Maybe replace `&#233;` with `&eacute;` in html/options.tmpl.

Other than that, the Template Toolkit describes use of filters.  For one reason or another the option items may be being filtered, or not. Maybe this can help you https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Template-Toolkit/lib/Template/Manual/Filters.pod#html_entity.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I had a `escape_html` in html/options.tmpl template file. Removing that, restored the exact acute accent character